# GAE background Threads not running in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine, python-2.7, queue

I need some help figuring out a problem with GAE background threads. What I'm trying to do is run a job on several threads using GAE background threads and Queue. The code runs on a Backend instance, and is kicked of by a TaskQueue. What I'm getting is that the jobs in the threads are running serially instead of in parallel, which sort of defeats the purpose.

```
from Queue import Queue
from google.appengine.api import background_thread
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue

q = Queue()

class Util():
   def work_in_background_thread(self):

       for p in portions:
            q.put(p)

        def _worker(index):
            portion = q.get()                
            do_work(portion)
            q.task_done()


        def do_work(snp_list):
            for snp in snp_list:
                self.find_snp_data(snp)


        for i in range(len(portions)):
            try:
                t = background_thread.BackgroundThread(target=_worker, args=[i])
                t.setDaemon(True)
                t.start()
            except:
                continue

        q.join()
```

The work is getting done, but threads run one after the other, so this job is taking hours to run!

Comment: Just curious, but have you tried defining your functions at the top level of the module? Maybe having them nested under a function which is nested under a Class is throwing it. Wouldn't think so logically, but I don't know how BackgroundThread might handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a backend then it's being run on a single instance and on the dev server it is impossible to get concurrency due to python [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) . I suspect that might be you issue. Also take a look [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) to understand that python cannot handle concurrency, but can handle threads to deliver better I/O

*EDIT*

Today there has been a new release of dev_server: Quoting from [the blog](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/app-engine-176-released.html):

> A major overhaul to the Python dev_appserver, the software used to
>   simulate App Engine while in development. The new dev_appserver is
>   multi-threaded, meaning development is faster, and provides a more
>   accurate simulation of the production environment.

Comment: GIL shouldn't stop threads from running concurrently; it should only stops threads from running _simultaneously_.

Comment: I agree but lets not play with words. From wiki: In computer science, concurrency is a property of systems in which several computations are executing simultaneously. Python cannot handle concurrency via threads. @allyourcode Yes GIL will stop threads from running concurrenly.

Comment: No, they are completely different. If you have only one core, threads cannot be executed simultaneously, no matter what language you are using, but they can be executed concurrently by context switching among threads, which is the way concurrency was done before multicore started taking over. If GIL prevented concurrent threads, App Engine would not support multiple threads in runtime: python27. This limitation exists only in runtime: python. In other words, this has nothing to do with Python GIL; it is an App-Engine-runtime-specific issue.

Comment: Yes excuses for me understanding concurrency as running in parallel. But for the point they are only words. But for the question the threads will execute one after another due to GIL or am I incorrect?

Comment: The GIL effectively prevents Python from executing on more than one core. Concurrency, however, is still possible via context switching (just like on a single core machine). My original point is this: the GIL is not why multithreading does not work in App Engine runtime: python. That limitation is specific to App Engine runtime: python. App Engine runtime: python27 still has the GIL, yet multithreading is supported there.

Comment: Excactely. We agree. I am saying the same thing. @allyourcode